# Encryption of Audio Codec

Tags: ios, objective-c, apache, http, encryption

For a commercial online music stores like itunes, is the encryption of the audio file performed before uploading the file on its server? or there is an encryption algorithm implemented on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel quite confident that the actual asset/file is exactly the same for everyone who downloads it. This would be a requirement for the file/asset to be distributed by a CDN (Content Distribution Network) which is how content providers present a huge, widely distributed user population with a consistent, fast experience when downloading content. I don't have any proprietary information, but based on twenty years developing distributed systems, this is the only approach that makes any sense from the server perspective.

Another answer posited that the content had to be individually encrypted for each user and said:

> A system like iTunes can only work properly if a different encryption key is used for each user.

There are plenty of ways to handle this that don't involve re-encrypting the payload for every user. For instance, each content file could have its own key, and then the client could perform a much smaller (compared to the size of the payload) cryptographic exchange with a server to get the key to unlock that content on purchase. The idea that every consumer of a multi-gigabyte movie causes that movie to be re-encrypted seems extremely improbable.

Comment: Yes, this does sound more sensible.